# Do I have access to GraphicsMagicks or ImageMagicks in a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: imagemagick, google-cloud-platform, graphicsmagick, google-cloud-functions

I want to make a Google Cloud Function that will correctly set the content type of uploaded files. I know how to do this with GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick, but I'm not sure if Google Cloud Function has those native libraries. How do I find out if they have them or failing that how do I get them installed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Google Cloud Functions run in a container that has ImageMagick installed. Somehow the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions#example_image_transformation) seems to have best documentation for it. From there:

> Cloud Functions provides an image-processing program called `ImageMagick` that can perform manipulations on graphical image files. The following is an example of how to create a thumbnail image for an uploaded image file:
>
> ```js
>     // Download file from bucket.
>     const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
>     const tempFilePath = `/tmp/${fileName}`;
>     return bucket.file(filePath).download({
>       destination: tempFilePath
>     }).then(() => {
>       console.log('Image downloaded locally to', tempFilePath);
>       // Generate a thumbnail using ImageMagick.
>       return exec(`convert "${tempFilePath}" -thumbnail '200x200>' "${tempFilePath}"`).then(() => {
>         console.log('Thumbnail created at', tempFilePath);
>         // We add a 'thumb_' prefix to thumbnails file name. That's where we'll upload the thumbnail.
>         const thumbFilePath = filePath.replace(/(\/)?([^\/]*)$/, `$1thumb_$2`);
>         // Uploading the thumbnail.
>         return bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {
>           destination: thumbFilePath
>         });
>       });
>     });
> ```
>
> This code executes the ImageMagick command line program convert to create a 200x200 thumbnail for the image saved in a temporary directory, then uploads it back to Cloud Storage.

Also see the Firebase functions-sample repo for an example of how to use it: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail

Comment: Wild, I saw that but wasn't sure it was the "same" cloud function. Shame they don't detail how to install other binaries.

Comment: You install other binaries by putting them in the same folder where your functions are. Either [Jason](https://cloudnext.withgoogle.com/schedule#target=building-serverless-applications-with-google-cloud-functions-c30bf9bd-c0ca-4256-b167-34a656b76703) or [Bret](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BybYim0HRmY) explained in a recent talk.

Comment: Thanks so much @frank-van-puffelen, that makes a lot of sense. I got so caught up in the world of package managers I forgot I could just ship a binary.

Comment: Same here: I had to actually learn that from one of our Cloud folks. I just realized it wasn't just in a video, but also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773497/can-you-call-out-to-ffmpeg-in-a-firebase-cloud-function

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen do you have any links for adding binaries? I'm having some trouble getting the exec to not return a 127 error code

Comment: Remember that they give you `convert` not the full package with `magick`