# Can I use ImageMagick 7.0 with Firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, imagemagick, heic

Trying to convert **HEIC** images to **JPEG**

I am working with Firebase functions when a new image is uploaded to the Firebase Storage.

It works when I run a test function locally in the firebase emulator, but fails when I try to run it on my Firebase project.

I realised my emulator is using ImageMagick 7.0.9-7 but my Firebase instance is using ImageMagick 6.9.7-4.

**How do I upgrade ImageMagick on my Firebase instance?**

Comment: You might need to install it as an additional binary, as shown in the links I included in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036268/do-i-have-access-to-graphicsmagicks-or-imagemagicks-in-a-google-cloud-function#comment73181621_43037070 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42777596/209103

Answer (score 0):

Adding Frank van Puffelen's answer as community wiki to improve visibility:

As said in Frank's answer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036268/do-i-have-access-to-graphicsmagicks-or-imagemagicks-in-a-google-cloud-function#comment73181621_43037070) you can add your own modules by putting them in the same folder as your Cloud Function. In the thread there's a link to Firebase tutorial with sample code on image processing triggered by upload.

In the other [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42777596/209103) provided there is information about ffmpeg, which is a library with quite a lot of multimedia capabilities, and explanations on how to install it.

You may also take a look at how to manage [dependencies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies) in Firebase.