# cloud functions - Node js Native Plugin support

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a third party tax calculation library which is written in C++. I would like to integrate with the Node JS through native plugins.

Does the cloud functions support the Node JS native plugins (libraries created in c++)?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions can invoke Node.js packages that depend on native libraries, as long as those libraries are included in the Node.js package.

For an example of that, see this question about using ffmpeg in Cloud Functions: [Can you call out to FFMPEG in a Firebase Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773497/can-you-call-out-to-ffmpeg-in-a-firebase-cloud-function)

Comment: Thank you. That’s very helpful