# Copy ffmpeg bins in multistage docker build

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, sh, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install ffmpeg via a multistage docker build

Here is the ffmpeg image that contains the ffmpeg binaries

```
FROM jrottenberg/ffmpeg
```

Here is the pm2 image that I need to run my web server

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2:8-alpine
```

I copy the bins into the current image, and I can see that ffmpeg, ffserver, and ffprobe all exist in /usr/local/bin.

```
COPY --from=0 /usr/local /usr/local
```

The copy command appears to succeed, since those files exist when I run the container interactively.

```
$# which ffmpeg
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

However, when I try running the bins, it says the command isn't found.

```
$# ffmpeg --version
/bin/sh: ffmpeg: not found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had a similar issue and ended up building my own binaries with no dependencies using the alpine gcc toolchain that supports building "static" PIE binaries. The reason was that I wanted no dependencies, hardened build and also support ASLR.

https://hub.docker.com/r/mwader/static-ffmpeg/

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense that you need to use the same base image for compatibility reasons. I was using `jrottenberg/ffmpeg` (which defaults to ubuntu). I should have been using `jrottenberg/ffmpeg:3.3-alpine` since I'm using the alpine-based pm2 image.

Also, building ffmpeg depends on some shared libraries, so copying /usr/local wasn't enough to make it work. I'm sure there's a more graceful solution, but I ended up just copying the root dir, which did the trick.

```
FROM jrottenberg/ffmpeg:3.3-alpine
# copy ffmpeg bins
COPY --from=0 / /
FROM <extension of 3.3-alpine>
```

Comment: Do you have the Dockerfile you used for this? I am hitting hte same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue opened [here](https://github.com/jrottenberg/ffmpeg/issues/99). And there is some solution for it like [this one](https://github.com/jrottenberg/ffmpeg/issues/99#issuecomment-396659630) and [this one](https://github.com/jrottenberg/ffmpeg/issues/99#issuecomment-400154614).