# How to use aria2c on cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

In the same way that a cloud function can run the ffmpeg, is possible download and run aria2c? If yes, how?

PS. `Cloud Run` isn't an option right now.

Edit: Something like this https://blog.qbatch.com/aws-lambda-custom-binaries-support-available-for-rescue-239aab820d60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing custom binaries like `aria2c` in the runtime are not supported in Cloud Functions.

You can find a **hacky** solution here: [Can you call out to FFMPEG in a Firebase Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773497/can-you-call-out-to-ffmpeg-in-a-firebase-cloud-function) This involves having a **statically linked** binary (so you might need to recompile `aria2c` as I'm assuming it won't be statically linked by default and it'll rely on more system packages like libc, libxxxx...) and bundling this library to your function deployment  fackage.

You **should** really consider using [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) for this use case. Cloud Run gives you the flexibility of creating your own container image that can include the binaries and libraries you want.

You can find a tutorial that bundles custom binaries on Cloud Run here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/system-packages