# Convert mp4 or Avi to m3u8 in pure node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, mp4, m3u8

I am searching a way to convert a mp4 or an .avi to .m3u8 in pure node js (firebase cloud function). Do you have ideas ?

Thank's, but I tried that :

```
const ffmpegInstaller = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegInstaller.path);
const ffmpeg_static = require('ffmpeg-static');
var cmd = ffmpeg('./flir_20191202T174341.mp4')
    .setFfmpegPath(ffmpeg_static.path)
    .videoBitrate(1024)
    .videoCodec('divx')
    .format('m3u8')
    .on('end', () => {
        // ...
    })
    .on('error', err => {
        console.error(err);
    })
    .save('./file-out.m3u8');
console.log('Hello !');
console.log(cmd);
```

And I have this error :

```
Error: Cannot find ffmpeg
at /Users/jeremy/Dev/ssv-api/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:136:22
at FfmpegCommand.proto._getFfmpegPath (/Users/jeremy/Dev/ssv-api/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/capabilities.js:90:14)
at FfmpegCommand.proto._spawnFfmpeg (/Users/jeremy/Dev/ssv-api/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:132:10)
at FfmpegCommand.proto.availableFormats.proto.getAvailableFormats (/Users/jeremy/Dev/ssv-api/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/capabilities.js:517:10)
at /Users/jeremy/Dev/ssv-api/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/capabilities.js:568:14
at nextTask (/Users/jeremy/Dev/ssv-api/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4576:27)
at Object.waterfall (/Users/jeremy/Dev/ssv-api/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4587:9)
at Object.awaitable [as waterfall] (/Users/jeremy/Dev/ssv-api/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:208:32)
at FfmpegCommand.proto._checkCapabilities (/Users/jeremy/Dev/ssv-api/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/capabilities.js:565:11)
at /Users/jeremy/Dev/ssv-api/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:298:14
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Jérémy.

Comment: I don't think pure nodejs can do this... FFmpeg can, but that's probably not available to a firebase cloud function...

Answer (score 2):

Found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42777596/8006046. It shows how you can run FFmpeg in the firebase cloud. You can replace `'path_or_readstream.mp4'` with either the path to the file you want to convert, or, which is more probable in a cloud function, you could pass the readable stream with the file you want to convert.

```js
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const ffmpeg_static = require('ffmpeg-static');

var cmd = ffmpeg('path_or_readstream.mp4')
  .setFfmpegPath(ffmpeg_static.path)
  .videoBitrate(1024)
  .videoCodec('divx')
  .format('m3u8')
  .on('end', () => {
    // ...
  })
  .on('error', err => {
    console.error(err);
  })
  .save('/tmp/file-out.m3u8');
```

Comment: @JérémyGachon You're using a different package than what this answer is using.

Comment: I tried with just fluent-ffmpeg ang ffmpeg-static, but there was this error. I searched on stack oveflow, and some persons said to add  ffmpegInstaller to set ffmpeg path. But there is alwais the error.