# How to install ffmpeg in node js for firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions

I am currently using firebase functions for a backend. I would like to change and edit data stored on firebase storage. I need to use ffmpeg https://ffmpeg.org. However, I do not know how I will be able to install ffmpeg in the node js firebase functions.

> I need ffmpeg to work in firebase functions (which use node.js)

I am thinking that I will use this node library https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg. Unless a better one is known.

Comment: Check out this question, it has multiple solution to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773497/can-you-call-out-to-ffmpeg-in-a-firebase-cloud-function