# Firebase (Cloud Functions) - Compile FFmpeg with video stabilization (vidstab)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase with the Cloud Functions feature and FFmpeg.

I see that FFmpeg is now included by default in the pre-installed packages, as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/system-packages).
This way, I can use it with a spawn command like this:

```
 await spawn('ffmpeg', [
      '-y',
      '-i',
      tempFilePath,
      '-vf',
      'transpose=2',
      targetTempFilePath,
    ]);
```

and it works perfectly.

Unfortunately, when I'm trying to stabilize the video with [vidstab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#vidstabdetect-1), it seems that I have the following error:

```
ChildProcessError: `ffmpeg -i /tmp/1628240712871_edited.mp4 -vf vidstabdetect=result=transforms.trf -an -f null -` failed with code 1
```

I think it's because `libvidstab` is not activated with FFmpeg, as stated below:

> To enable compilation of this filter, you need to configure FFmpeg with
> --enable-libvidstab.

Do you have any idea how I can activate/use it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would say that the binary that comes default in Cloud Functions can not be modified to enable libvidstab. However, as mentioned over at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773497/can-you-call-out-to-ffmpeg-in-a-firebase-cloud-function), you can upload your own binary with the appropriate configuration to meet your needs

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's what I did :)

Answer (score 1):

For your information, I achieved to do it.

I had to upload my own binary. For that, I just downloaded a pre-compiled Debian-based Linux environment binary ([here](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/), but you can have your own anywhere else ;) ) and put it inside the functions directory.
After that, I just deployed the functions, as usual.

This would result in the functions being deployed along with the binary.

I can now call my own binary with a command like this:

```
import { spawn } from 'child-process-promise';
...
await spawn('./ffmpeg', [
  // my commands
]);
```

I hope it helps ;)