# Google Cloud Platform: Convert uploaded MP4 file to HLS file

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg, google-cloud-transcoder

I am building a platform, that allows users to upload some video files (20-40 seconds) from their phone to server. All this upload is working great for now, files are stored in google storage bucket via nodejs cloud functions.

Now I want to create a gcp transcoder-job, that will convert uploaded .mp4 video file to .hls video stream with .ts chunks of 2-4 seconds duration.

Probably success scenario:

1. User uploads mp4 file **[Done]**
2. .mp4 file after upload triggers `functions.storage.object().onFinalize` **[Done]**
3. `onFinalize` triggers Google Cloud Job, that will convert mp4 to hls. **[We are here]**
4. .mp4 file is removed from google storage.

Will appreciate any help on creating such job.
I am using firebase cloud functions with nodejs.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one has been helpful. See [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for info.

Comment: Hey @JakeNelson, sorry for delay. Thanks for your answer - guided me in the right direction of the search.

Comment: @PeteStreem Hi! I am also implementing the scenario. Can you please share your journey and how you achieved this task?

Comment: @Mrcreamio Sorry man, I have not finished that project and it is still on hold for now due to war in our country. If I remember correctly, I tried to tigger a transcoder job on special google api, called Pipelines. You can create any pipeline you want (mp4->hls) and call it each time, user uploads mp4 file. Inside pipeline I used a nodejs library that decoded video stream. If you achieve a success story, will be also pleased if you share some instructions.

Comment: @PeteStreem Thank you for replying. Sure I will share my journey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this using the [transcoder API in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/quickstart). It supports mp4 input and hls output. See [supported formats](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/concepts/overview#supported_inputs_outputs)

Note that videos must be greater than 5 seconds in length.
If they can't be 5 seconds in length, maybe avoid this API and using a tool on AppEngine.

A rough flow of events to accomplish this could be something like:

1. Upload MP4 to bucket
2. [pubsub is triggered from the upload event](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications)
3. This can trigger a cloud function that can [create a new Transcoder job](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/jobs#create-job-from-template-nodejs)
4. The job status [updates a pubsub topic](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/create-pub-sub)
5. Pubsub topic triggers a cloud function when the [status](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.jobs#status) indicates the job is done
6. Cloud function deletes the original mp4 from the bucket

Comment: Very expensive solution. Especially for a video of big size.

Comment: @Xenolion, suggest a cheaper one as an answer so people can use that.

Comment: Transcoder API is very expensive for smaller videos like what the asker has stated I would recommend to use `ffmpeg` directly in a cloud function. Thanks to google now ffmpeg is available in cloud function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773497/can-you-call-out-to-ffmpeg-in-a-firebase-cloud-function